# Rails: How to access self.method in another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

```
class Foo1
  def self.foo1action(cake)
    # returns user object
  end
end

class Foo2
  def foo2action
    user = # here i want call foo1action
  end
end
```

How do i call foo1action in foo2action?
This is based on rails framework. I know that inheriting is one way to go... I want to know other way of doing this..

Comment: what you wrote is not even a valid Ruby

Comment: if its due to syntax... pls ignore

Comment: `foo1.foo1action(whatever)` But calling another controllers method is highly suspicious; if they have shared behavior you either want a base controller, a module/mixin/concern, a service method, etc.

Comment: just to point out that `self.foo1action(cake)` is a class-method whereas `def foo2action` is an instance-method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo1
  def self.foo_1_action(cake)
  end
end

class Foo2
  def foo_2_action
    user = ::Foo1.foo_1_action(some_cake)
  end
end
```